# Why is the comma separeted or named range SEARCH() function not working in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to search a text in cell for predefined keywords in Excel 2016. I am using the SEARCH() function. Whatever I do as soon as I enter multiple "find_text" my SEARCH function return "#VALUE!" error.

My "within_text" is a cell within a table column called 'Message'. the text is "Exception while booking new deal, error: Unknown Error( 0 )" and the keywords I am searching are {"Success","Unknown","Failed"}

```
=SEARCH({"Success","Unknown","Failed"},Q_DTL_GetAll__3[@MESSAGE])
```

I even used Named Range like so

```
=SEARCH(Test,Q_DTL_GetAll__3[@MESSAGE])
```

Everytime I am getting the "#VALUE!" error whereas I am expecting the position of the word "Unknown" from the within_text.

Comment: Are you using Ctrl+Shift+Enter ?  Also your formula will report one result for each trial, so you can't just use a single cell here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if it can only contain one of those words, then where it doesn't contain one of the keywords the SEARCH function will return an error.  Capture that using IFERROR to set errors (values not found) to 0, and then get the MAX to find the position of the word that was found (if any).  If no values are found, then the result will just be 0:

```
=MAX(INDEX(IFERROR(SEARCH({"Success","Unknown","Failed"},Q_DTL_GetAll__3[@Message]),0),))
```

Comment: This worked. I thought that the SEARCH function is iterative and searches all the keywords.

Comment: @Priyam It is iterative, but an error for any result will mean the function returns an error for the final result.  That's why you have to capture any errors using IFERROR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normally entered function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,SEARCH({"Success","Unknown","Failed"},Q_DTL_GetAll__3[@MESSAGE]),1)
```

Your `SEARCH` is returning an array of values. In the given case:

`{#VALUE!,42,#VALUE!}`

So you need some way of only returning the non-error value.  `AGGREGATE` can do that.

This formula will return a `#NUM!` error if none of the words are present.  You can handle that as you wish.